# No IDP was configured error in app using spring-security-saml

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-saml

I'm writing a web app with Spring Boot and Spring Security SAML based on the sample code at https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample.  When I try to access a secure URL in my app I get this exception:

```
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP
```

I'm configuring an IDP as follows:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("idp-wwu")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate wwuExtendedMetadataProvider() throws MetadataProviderException {
    log.debug("Adding wwu IDP metadata provider");
    @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation"})
    HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider("https://sidp.wwu.edu/idp/profile/Metadata/SAML", 5000);
    httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("metadata")
public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
    providers.add(wwuExtendedMetadataProvider());
    log.debug("Added wwu IDP metadata provider");
    return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
}
```

From debug output, it looks like the IDP has been configured:

```
2015-01-20 09:08:07.097 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] e.w.a.r.g.config.WebSecurityConfig       : Adding wwu IDP metadata provider
2015-01-20 09:08:07.131 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] e.w.a.r.g.config.WebSecurityConfig       : Added wwu IDP metadata provider
2015-01-20 09:08:07.169 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Creating metadata reload timer with interval 10000
2015-01-20 09:08:07.172 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Clearing metadata cache
2015-01-20 09:08:07.172 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Reloading metadata
2015-01-20 09:08:07.173 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Refreshing metadata provider org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@71728250
2015-01-20 09:08:07.173 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Trust verification skipped for metadata provider org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@71728250
2015-01-20 09:08:07.175 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Created new trust manager for metadata provider org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@71728250
2015-01-20 09:08:07.176 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Adding signature filter
2015-01-20 09:08:07.176 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Initializing extendedMetadataDelegate org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@71728250
2015-01-20 09:08:07.176 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.s.m.ExtendedMetadataDelegate       : Initializing delegate
2015-01-20 09:08:07.477  INFO 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider : New metadata succesfully loaded for 'https://sidp.wwu.edu/idp/profile/Metadata/SAML'
2015-01-20 09:08:07.480  INFO 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider : Next refresh cycle for metadata provider 'https://sidp.wwu.edu/idp/profile/Metadata/SAML' will occur on '2015-01-20T20:08:07.287Z' ('2015-01-20T12:08:07.287-08:00' local time)
2015-01-20 09:08:07.480 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Initializing provider data org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@71728250
2015-01-20 09:08:07.481 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Found metadata EntityDescriptor with ID
2015-01-20 09:08:07.482 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Remote entity https://sidp.wwu.edu/idp/shibboleth available
2015-01-20 09:08:07.483 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Metadata provider was initialized org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@71728250
2015-01-20 09:08:07.483 DEBUG 50730 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.saml.metadata.MetadataManager      : Reloading metadata was finished
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in the [metadata you're importing](https://sidp.wwu.edu/idp/profile/Metadata/SAML) - it's incomplete. There's no element `IDPSSODescriptor`, therefore no IDP to import:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://sidp.wwu.edu/idp/shibboleth" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ContactPerson contactType="other" xmlns:icmd="http://id.incommon.org/metadata"><GivenName>Linc Nesheim</GivenName><EmailAddress xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">linc.nesheim@wwu.edu</EmailAddress></ContactPerson></EntityDescriptor>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks!  Apparently the IDP sysadmin made a change that broke the metadata.  Other SPs were working because they were using older, correct, metadata.